# phonegap transparent textarea

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

I am creating a mobile app for android using phonegap.
In html i have a body with a custom background (vertical lines and horizontal lines).
On top of the body i have a textarea which has background transparent.

When i "click" on the textarea on desktop everything is ok.But when i "click" the textarea on device it becomes white.

How can i make it transparent on click too ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: it is ok , but now i can not enter text.the keyboard shows but text is not entered